# Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed in Angular-11 Application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-ui-router

with *ngFor, I cannot fetch the data from my component.ts to my component.html

The same method works for one class but does not work for another class.

**Here is my service class**

```
export class FoodListService {
  private url = environment.serverURL;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  //get all products from one store
  getAllProducts(storeId: Number): Observable<FoodListModelServer[]> {
    return this.http.get<FoodListModelServer[]>(this.url + 'foodlist/' + storeId);
  }
```

**Here is my component class**

```
export class FoodListComponent implements OnInit {

  foodlist: FoodListModelServer[] = [];
  
constructor(private foodListService: FoodListService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    
      this.foodListService.getAllProducts(this.storeId).subscribe(food => {

        this.foodlist = food;
        console.log(this.foodlist);
      });    
   }
}
```

**Here is my component.html**

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-lg-10 col-sm-6 card">
        <li *ngFor="let foodlist of foodlist">
            {{foodlist.food_name}}
            
        </li>
</div>
```

**Console.log(this.foodlist)**

I get and object **{count: 5, stores: Array(5)}**

Why do I get a count included forming an object instead of just the Array?

How do I get only the array?

I have same code with the other component and it works fine. I tried everything mentioned online with no progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do I get a count included forming an object instead of just the
> Array?

- it depends on the implementation of API on the backend side

> How do I get only the array?

1. create interface for the actual response from API and use here `this.http.get<FoodListModelServerResponse>`
2. then we can extract value from response via RxJs `map` operator - `map(response => response.stores)` (find more info here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map)
3. that is it, you can subscribe to `getAllProducts` and you will get the array

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface FoodListModelServerResponse {
count: number;
stores: FoodListModelServer[];
}

export class FoodListService {
  private url = environment.serverURL;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getAllProducts(storeId: Number): Observable<FoodListModelServer[]> {
    return this.http.get<FoodListModelServerResponse >(this.url + 'foodlist/' + storeId)
.pipe(map(response => response.stores));
  }
```

then you can use your implementation

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    
      this.foodListService.getAllProducts(this.storeId).subscribe(food => {

        this.foodlist = food;
        console.log(this.foodlist);
      });    
   }
}
```

Comment: I got an error, type does not exist in the model: "Property 'stores' does not exist on type 'FoodListModelServer[]'."

Comment: please follow the correct way

Comment: it is because method `getAllProducts`  has returned type Observable<FoodListModelServer[]> but in reality it is `FoodListModelServerResponse ` that I have created

Comment: Using the pipe solved the issue (.pipe(map(response => response.stores));) Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use RxJs [pluck](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/pluck) operator to extract `stores` out of response object.
Declare `foodlist` variable as `foodlist$: Observable<FoodListModelServer[]>` so that it is assignable to observable.

In foodService return `Observable<any>` like
`getAllProducts(storeId: Number): Observable<any>`

```
import { pluck} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class FoodListComponent implements OnInit {

    foodlist$: Observable<FoodListModelServer[]>;
      
    constructor(private foodListService: FoodListService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
          this.foodlist$ = this.foodListService.getAllProducts(this.storeId).pipe(
            pluck('stores')
          ); 
     }
}
```

In template use [Async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe), it will take care of subscribing and unsubscribing to your `foodListService.getAllProducts`

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-lg-10 col-sm-6 card">
    <li *ngFor="let foodlist of foodlist$ | async">
        {{foodlist.food_name}}
    </li>
</div>
```